# how to define path to superpom?

Tags: java, maven-3

Any maven experts out there?  I inherited a huge maven project and am trying to get it to compile.  Not getting very far.  I go to the highest level pom.xml I can find, located in trunk directory, one level down from the main project.  Then I issue command "mvn validate".  Get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mycompany/neto/vsd/vsd-superpom/1.1.0/vsd-superpom-1.1.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.mycompany.neto.vsd:vsd-superpom:pom:1.1.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

I noticed a vsd-superpom folder at the same level as the main project so I'm guessing the main project needs to point to it somewhere?  Looking at the pom.xml I see

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.neto.vsd</groupId>
    <artifactId>vsd-superpom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</parent>
```

Where do I put the vsd-superpom folder so that it will be found?  I don't understand why it tries to download it.  I don't see anything in pom.xml that tells it to do that.

Comment: The run of mvn tries to download non existing dependencies into your local repository. The repository is in a folder named .M2 on your machine in your user directory. So, if you put the whole structure with the superpom found in your project there it should run.

Comment: @NwDx that the local repository is located in the folder .M2 is not really true. The default is `${user.home}/.m2/repository`  see [Maven Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html). The location of the local repository can be configured either via the  global `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml` or the users `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apache Maven has a two level strategy to resolve and distribute files, which we call artifacts. The first level is called the local repository, which is the artifact cache on your system, by default located at ${user.home}/.m2/repository. When executing Maven, it'll first look in this local cache for artifacts. If the artifact cannot be found here, Maven will access the remote repositories to find the artifact. Once found it will be stored into the local repository, so it's be available for current and future usage.

see [Apache Maven Install Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) Documentation

So if your super pom is independent of the rest of the project you can simply invoke `mvn install` from the super pom folder so that it will be placed into your local repository. That will solve your problem.

Usually the top-level project pom defines the project dependencies and it should be enough to invoke `mvn verify | compile | ...`

If the top-level pom depends on the super pom that you have to install the super pom first (or define a pom that contains the submodules super pom and rest of the project)

Comment: I went to the vsd-superpom folder and saw that it's pom.xml was located in the trunk folder.  So I went to the trunk folder and did "mvn install" as you suggested.  It seemed to run ok.  Said it was downloading a bunch of stuff and did not produce any errors.  However, when I went back to the main pom.xml and again typed "mvn validate", I got the same error as before.  I went into the .m2/repository folder and could see there was a com/mycompany/neto/vsd/vsd-superpom-1.2.0.xml file so it would seem that it put it where it was supposed to.

Comment: I see the version is different.  Man, this is right out of subversion!  I changed the version to 1.2.0 and now all is good!  Thank you so much and to all who replied!

Answer (score 0):

Common project structure what I have seen (and used) is:

- **foo-parent**

  - `pom.xml` - parent POM for my modules with parent `../pom.xml`
- **foo-module**

  - `pom.xml` - module POM with parent `../foo-parent/pom.xml`
- *...other modules...*
- `pom.xml` - multimodule POM without a parent

Now if I want to build *foo-module* I need to be in the top-level folder and run:

```
mvn -pl foo-module -am package
```

In other words you are always building the multi-module project. However you can specify that you are interested only in some submodules (`-pl`) and their dependencies (`-am`).